# how to find the lower limits of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves.

$y^2 = x, \ x = 2y; \ about \ the \ y-axis$

Why isn't the lower limit of integration -2?

Comment: but aren't you rotating the washer?

Answer (score 0):

Identify the top and bottom functions:
$$
\begin{align}
  \color{red}{y_{t}(x)} &= \color{red}{\frac{1}{2} x}, \\
  \color{blue}{y_{b}(x)} &= \color{blue}{x^{2}}.
\end{align}
$$

Bottom intersection at $(0,0)$; top at $\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4} \right)$.

[image: slice]

Volume of revolution
$$
 V = \pi \int_{0}^{1/2}
\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{2} x\right)^{2}}  -
\color{blue}{\left( x^{2} \right)^{2}} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{240}
$$

Comment: Answer the question – the OP is asking about the lower limit of integration, not the volume of revolution

Comment: @TobyMak I think this answer makes it clear that the lower limit of integration should _not_ be $-2$, and signals that the OP might have found the wrong region.

Comment: OK Sorry for my mistake